# drop down with nested ul elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have some nested ul elements. I want the hidden ul elements to drop down when the parent li element is clicked. I got this to work, however, it drops down every ul element with my "dropDown" class. How can I get it to drop down just the child ul of the li that is clicked?

```
<ul id="Ben" class="standDrop">
    <li class="dropClick">First li
        <img class="dropImg" src="img/preDropArrw.svg">
    </li>
    <!--nested ul for drowdown-->
    <ul class="dropDown">
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
    </ul>
    <!--end nested ul for drowdown-->
    <li class="dropClick">second li
        <img class="dropImg" src="img/preDropArrw.svg">
    </li>
    <!--nested ul for drowdown-->
    <ul class="dropDown">
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
        <li>info</li>
    </ul>
    <!--end nested ul for drowdown-->
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropDown").hide();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropClick").click(function () {

        $(".dropDown").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure the HTML slightly to achieve this:

```
<ul id="Ben" class="standDrop">
    <li class="dropClick">First li
        <img class="dropImg" src="img/preDropArrw.svg" />
        <!--nested ul for drowdown-->
        <ul class="dropDown">
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!--end nested ul for drowdown-->
    <li class="dropClick">second li
        <img class="dropImg" src="img/preDropArrw.svg" />
        <!--nested ul for drowdown-->
        <ul class="dropDown">
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
            <li>info</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!--end nested ul for drowdown-->
</ul>
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropDown").hide();

    $(".dropClick").click(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find(".dropDown").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Working [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WXBz5/)

2 Changes

a. Make the `ul.dropDown` element child of `li.dropClick`

b. Use `$this.find(".dropDown")` to find the clicked elements' corresponding menu.

Comment: thanks! I should have know better the html, but I would have never got the jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery method "find" or "children" to find element that are within a specific selector. Since your "dropClick" element is the one the click occurs on, a "this" reference inside that event handler will refer to that element. Then, using "find" or "children" you will reference only the elements matching your selector inside the "this" element. Children will only grab the items immediately within the element where "find" will search the whole sub-tree, finding submenus you might have as well.

jQuery doc on Children: http://api.jquery.com/children/
jQuery doc on Find: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Code for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropClick").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".dropDown").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I was answering as the other was posted and didn't even notice the UL outside the LI. As karthikr pointed out, the structure should be changed so the UL is a subnode of the LI. The spec specifies that only LIs be the children of ULs. Sub lists must be contained within a list item.